# Remove part for an lvm mirror

Tags: lvm

I am trying to remove some drives from an LVM stripe.  The kernel wont free up the file system but I managed to move all of the activity off of it so I decided I would mirror the data to a network file system and then remove the original drives from the file system so that what was busy was the network file system part of the mirror.

This is my mirror

```
  lv_home1            vg_home mwi-aom--- 1.77t                                [lv_home1_mlog] 100.00          
  [lv_home1_mimage_0] vg_home iwi-aom--- 1.77t                                                                
  [lv_home1_mimage_1] vg_home iwi-aom--- 1.77t                                                                
  [lv_home1_mlog]     vg_home lwi-aom--- 4.00
```

lv_home1_mimage_0 is hosted on /dev/md1(0),/dev/sde(0),/dev/sdf(0),/dev/sdg(0),/dev/sdh(0)
lv_home1_mimage_1 is hosted on /dev/loop1(0)

So I tried
lvconvert -m0 /dev/vg_home/lv_home1 /dev/md1

But that kept /dev/md1 and it's brethern (/dev/sde(0),/dev/sdf(0),/dev/sdg(0),/dev/sdh(0) in lv_home1.
How do I break the mirror and keep the lv on lv_home1_mimage_, /dev/loop1(0)?

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer seems to be to list all of the devices in the wrong part of the mirror.
 lvconvert  -m0 //dev/vg_home/lv_home1 /dev/sde /dev/sdf /dev/sdg /dev/sdh /dev/md1

Originally I tried 
lvconvert -m0 /dev/vg_home/lv_home1 /dev/md1
becuase I thought it would delete /dev/md1 and everything else it need to but that failed and instead it removed /dev/loop1 from the mirror.